# How to create a connected application in SalesForce to be able add the OAuth2 authorization to my SalesForce Rest service

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, apexrest, connected-apps, chrome

I'm going to create a Chrome extension that will get some data from my SalesForce Rest service. I need to add the OAuth2 authorization to this service. How to correctly set up such a service via a connected application in SalesForce? Most commonly I don't know what I should add to the "Callback URL" field. And I actually didn't find a good explanation of what to do if you're doing this with your service hosted in SalesForce. Does anybody try to do this via a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 3):

The callback URL should be *https://**extension-id**.chromiumapp.org/index.html*, where **extension-id** is the ID assigned to your app. You'll also need to use the `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` method in order for this callback URL to work.