# Authenticate to Salesforce in Chrome extension

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, oauth

crosspost from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75872075/authenticate-to-salesforce-in-chrome-extension)

I am trying to authenticate to Salesforce in Chrome extension, but I am getting 400 error. If I try this code in Express.js server, it works.

**background.js**

```
console.log("Extension loaded");

let user_signed_in = false;
const clientId =
  "xyz";
const callbackUrl = "https://dfghlbaebomdoihlfmegbpcmfkfgfno.chromiumapp.org";

const getSalesforceLoginLink = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${callbackUrl}`
  );

  if (res.status === 200) {
    // append login link
    return res.url;
  } else {
    console.error("Not able to fetch login link");
  }
};

const authenticateSalesforce = (salesforceLink) => {
  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
    {
      url: salesforceLink,
      interactive: true,
    },
    function (redirect_url) {
      const codeParam = searchParams.get('code');
      let authCode = codeParam;
      const loginUrl = `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=${
    process.env.SALESFORCE_CALLBACK_URL
  }&client_id=${process.env.SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${
    process.env.SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET
  }&code=${encodeURIComponent(authCode)}`;
  const response = await fetch(loginUrl)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response?.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      return data;
    });
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        sendResponse({ message: "fail" });
      } else {
        console.log({ redirect_url });
      }
    }
  );
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.message === "login") {
    if (user_signed_in) {
      console.log("User is already signed in.");
    } else {
      const salesforceLink = await getSalesforceLoginLink();
      authenticateSalesforce(salesforceLink);
    }

    return true;
  } else if (request.message === "logout") {
    user_signed_in = false;
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "./popup.html" }, () => {
      sendResponse({ message: "success" });
    });

    return true;
  }
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "SF POC",
  "description": "A quick way to browse top posts from DEV Community.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "action": {
    "default_title": "SF POC"
  },
  "key": "xyz",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["identity", "activeTab", "tabs", "windows"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://login.salesforce.com/*"]
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post the raw request being sent in the Chrome Console

Comment: @BryanAnderson thanks for checking. I edited my question where I added screenshot with raw request

Comment: its saying bad request, can you show each URL parameter your passing (you can redact any sensitive information) to see how it is being constructed

Comment: @BryanAnderson it's visible in the last screenshot. This is the url: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xyz&redirect_uri=https://dfghlaebomdoihlfmegbpcmfkfgfno.chromiumapp.org`

Comment: Would you be able to add the client Id? I would like to try from my end. The client id can be publicly shared

Comment: @BryanAnderson yes, `client_id` is `3MVG9QV5z8XnLDvyzCV3CMQEpDOpTAEQq8UhLbjD4YaTRjEKXnRxKp8VzS0bEZQJWDHrXRtBY_HTC0BSeqCBW`

Comment: So the issue is, your redirect URI is not matching what is in your connected app configuration `error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration`

Comment: @BryanAnderson yeah, I tried to made some changes to fix it, but it didn't help and I didn't revert the configuration. I just changed the callback url to `https://decmdfbaebomdoihlfmegbpcmfkfgfno.chromiumapp.org` and the correct request url is `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9QV5z8XnLDvyzCV3CMQEpDOpTAEQq8UhLbjD4YaTRjEKXnRxKp8VzS0bEZQJWDHrXRtBY_HTC0BSeqCBW&redirect_uri=https://decmdfbaebomdoihlfmegbpcmfkfgfno.chromiumapp.org`

Comment: I just tried your new URL and it works

Comment: @BryanAnderson thanks for checking. I just tried it out again and I am getting CORS error https://imgur.com/a/uisgGga I am wondering if it's possible to authenticate on the client without a server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145123/discussion-between-bryan-anderson-and-matt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need your chrome extension to open a tab have the user go to that URL
you then need your chome extension to listen for the callback
instead doing a JS `fetch`

As outlined by @sfdcfox in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203407/how-to-create-a-connected-application-in-salesforce-to-be-able-add-the-oauth2-au/203408#203408) you will need to use the [chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/#method-launchWebAuthFlow) method